# Embeded Flash in ASP.NET page iis 7.5 local flash file

Tags: asp.net, flash, iis-7.5

I'm trying to add Embeded flash in aspx page running on iis 7.5 windows server 2008.
When i'm adding the Embeded code src=/mylocation/test.swf it works fine.
But when I'm adding fileserver location src="file:\\c:\test.swf the page doesn't load.
The code works fine in normal html file on my desktop.

What should I do?
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I think IIS filters out physical file paths. Use a virtual path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should have that file inside your web site and use a relative path to reach it. IIS can then reach the file.